# How to Change Costumes of Sprites in pygame

Tags: pygame-surface

How can I animate the costumes of sprites while the main loop is running? **(Pygames)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use threading.

Create another thread in which a variable changes every second.

for example:

```
import threading
import time

SleepTimeChar = 0.01

class CostumeIndexPlayer (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        global costumeIndex
        while costumeIndex < 5:
            if costumeIndex == 0:
                time.sleep(SleepTimeChar)
                costumeIndex = 1
            elif costumeIndex == 1:
                time.sleep(SleepTimeChar)
                costumeIndex = 2
            elif costumeIndex == 2:
                time.sleep(SleepTimeChar)
                costumeIndex = 3
            elif costumeIndex == 3:
                time.sleep(SleepTimeChar)
                costumeIndex = 0

IndexPlayer = CostumeIndexPlayer()
IndexPlayer.start()
```

Later you can use the same variable as an index number

```
import pygame    

playerImg = [pygame.image.load('1.png'), pygame.image.load('2.png'), pygame.image.load('3.png'), pygame.image.load('4.png')]

def player(x, y):
        window.blit(playerImg[costumeIndex], (x, y))
```